# How to start log on the fly in terminal?

Tags: linux

I want to know command that view the live view of `/var/log/messages` file on the **terminal**?

so, I can monitor **system activity** log

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your `Linux` distribution (specifically, *userland* tools you have - `GNU`, `busybox` etc) you may have luck with either of these:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages

$ tailf /var/log/messages

$ less +F /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
cat /var/log/messages
```

It will give a whole lot of messages on the terminal.

Using the tail (told by Arkadiusz Drabczyk) command will keep the command running and you won't need to put the cat command again and again.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can call that **live view** which the OP asked for.

Comment: Agreed! I modified my answer.